# Is it possible to hide the bottom tab in Chrome on OS X using keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

When you use Google Chrome on OS X and download some stuff while web-surfing, a tab shows up on the bottom on which the downloaded contents and its progress status will be displayed.

However, I don't like to bother to closing the tab after the download is successfully done by moving the cursor and tapping on the *x* icon.

Is it possible to close the tab via a shortcut? Or ideally, is it possible to automatically close the tab once the download has been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at this post on our sister site...
https://superuser.com/questions/111675/google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar/325787

There are multiple methods given, including an extension that can do this automatically, as well as an Applescript that can run as a service and be activated with a keyboard shortcut.